# Count how many times the button is clicked in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have 5 buttons and I want when I click each of them it will count. For example I clicked the button 1, the counter should increment 1, and when I clicked the button 2 the counter should increment 1 again. So the total of counter to be displayed is 2. Below is the code I've done so far, but it's not working as I expected. What should I have to do ?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('check', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.count = function(inc){
    
    $scope.counter += inc;
  };
  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="check">
 
  <button id = '1' ng-click = "count(1)" >1 </button>
  <button id = '2' ng-click = "count(1)" >2 </button>
  <button id = '3' ng-click = "count(1)" >3 </button>
  <button id = '4' ng-click = "count(1)" >4 </button>
  <button id = '5' ng-click = "count(1)" >5 </button>
  <label> Total Count : {{counter}} </label>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare the counter in the controller:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('check', function ($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;
    $scope.count = function (inc) {
        $scope.counter += inc;
    };
});
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnotp1pc/

Comment: What if I want to set a limit when the button is clicked. Example the limit is 3. Every click of button it will alert 1 of 3, 2 of 3 and when the click is exceeds to 3 it will alert stop?

Comment: @Prisoner yes I know and I'm doing it. Just a new bit here in angular js. I am not asking for the full source code. I just want a suggestions and advice. :-)

Comment: `ng-if` is good at this: `<span ng-if="counter < 4">Click more</span>` see http://jsfiddle.net/mnotp1pc/1/

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize $scope.counter to zero

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('check', function($scope) {
  $scope.counter= 0;
  $scope.count = function(inc){
    
    $scope.counter += inc;
  };
  
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="check">
 
  <button id = '1' ng-click = "count(1)" >1 </button>
  <button id = '2' ng-click = "count(1)" >2 </button>
  <button id = '3' ng-click = "count(1)" >3 </button>
  <button id = '4' ng-click = "count(1)" >4 </button>
  <button id = '5' ng-click = "count(1)" >5 </button>
  <label> Total Count : {{counter}} </label>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to initialise the counter variable as 0, **$scope.counter = 0**